# Showing warning message when shareing on facebook in iPhone app

Tags: ios, sharekit, facebook-sharer

I am a new ios developer. I have creating an iPhone application where i want to use "Sharekit" Framework. To do this i have complete all setup which is described in share kit documentation.
But when i want to share then the showing the following message

"ERROR:This endpoint has been deprecated.To temporarily reenable it,you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disable permanently on August 1,2012."

I do not know what i miss. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably using old, obsolete original ShareKit. You might want to try [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/), which is maintained and updated.

edit:

The new shareKit has a lot of changes when you compare it with original, so it is wise to re-add it from scratch, and CAREFULLY follow [the new install guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). If you experience this same error even after setting up ShareKit 2.0, it is a sign that you are still using old obsolete version of FBConnect (facebook-ios-sdk). In this case make sure, that you use the new one - it is in Submodules/facebook-ios-sdk folder.

Comment: What exactly did not work? ShareKit 2.0 has changed a lot when compared with original ShareKit, so it might be good to re-add it from scratch. Make sure you follow [wiki installation guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) REALLY carefully

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I used FBConnect. Facebook has scheduled several "breaking changes". This particular one was forced on everyone on Aug 1st 2012. So, disabling the Breaking Change won't help anymore.

Technically speaking, ShareKit should fix the problem. However, you should really check to see if the feature was working for you. Go to:

```
Apps>>your app>>Insights>>See All
```

Then apply the formula:

```
Value = extra app sales just for having the feature + sales due to sharing on FB - yearly maintenance cost to update FB software - customer service cost for FB bugs - lost sales due to disgruntled FB users.
```

In my case, Value was negative so I removed the feature from my top-selling iOS app. FBConnect was the most buggy part of my app and it unfortunately did more damage than good.

For those interested, here are the bugs we encountered:

- FBConnect would break when people changed their password on FB but the session key was still valid. There was no way to detect this so people just got hung.
- FBConnect would time out quite often for no particular reason (assume this was server issues on their end).
- FBConnect didn't handle out-of-coverage (no internet) connections very well.

I'm not ranting here, I'm just providing a technical insight which is important to consider before determining the correct way to fix the problem. Updating the SDK is the right solution for some people, but not everyone.

Answer (score 0):

open app in facebook "http://developers.facebook.com/"

apps>>your app >> setting >>Edit settings>> Advanced>>Migrations>>Disable all Breaking Changed

it will work.

Comment: Until they make (made) the breaking change on August 1.

Comment: Now its not working  and this option we are not having to disable "August 2012 Breaking Changes",, i have tried with breaking change disabled, still it is not working , i am getting the same error.